# How to read coordinates from file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, file-read

I have got a file with coordinates of robot that contains X,Y of robot and degree of rotation.

```
0.2 0.3 150
1.7 3.2 -30
.....
8.7 5.2 -120
```

I have got also a file with different readings from robot sensors that look like

```
1.5 1.4 1.0. 1.5
4.5 3.4 8.3. 1.1
....
3.5 7.3 1.2. 12.5
```

And firstly I read coordinates of robot and then its sensor values and do some calculations. Is there any point to create a class for robot poses that will keep there variables?

```
double x,y; int degrees;
```

Because it is easier to make just an array of double[linesInFile][3] that will keep all values as double type that to create class of position and create array of position objects.
And what is the best way to create that array if I dont know how many coordinates is in the file and I dont know the size of array till I read whole file? Can they be added dynamicalt or should I read how many lines is in the file firstly and then create new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a struct stored in a std::vector.

```
   struct Coord {
     double x;
     double y;
     double deg;
   };

   std::vector<Coord> myCoords;
```

Now you can use push_back to add elements. std::vector will take care of memory management for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a class.

If you don't know the size of an array in advance, just use a `std::vector`, and add each element to the vector, as you read its information from a file.

Reading the file twice, once to determine the number of rows, and the second time for real, is so ...last century, when all we had was C. Fortunately, we have C++ now, with `std::vector`, and many other powerful classes and templates, that makes it completely unnecessary to go through such hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You can read using `std::cin` and the overloaded `operator >>`. It depends on your code, but probably the easiest is to create a simple struct that holds the necessary variables.

For a dynamically allocated array, use `std::vector`. It's a template container and will work with your struct.

```
struct Coo {
    double x,y;
    double deg;
}

std::vector< Coo > vec_cont;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wanna make it dynamic, just read through the file and record the number of lines.

Dynamic, use vector of objects. create a

```
struct Movement {
  double x,y;
  int degrees;
};
```

use it in something like :

```
vector<Movement> myMovement;
```

then you can add each line as an object of Movement.